# Upgrading Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, 11.10, upgrade

It is necessary to update my Ubuntu 11.10 even though I'm happy.

But now it tells me that my system will be no longer protected according to what I want to do.

Comment: please check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release